# Where can one find Plus ATMs in rural Taiwan?

Tags: money, taiwan

When I got to Taipei, my card worked with the ATMs I find, so I did not think much of it. Now that I am starting to circle Taiwan clockwise, I am have not yet found an ATM that accepts Plus cards. Keelung, Jiufen and Xincheng, so far no luck and am getting low on cash. Even places that accept cards like the 7-11 for purchases (Tried Keelung and Xincheng) did not accept my Plus cards nor Mastercard or VISA.

**Where can I find ATMs that accept Plus debit cards between Taroko and Sun Moon lake?**

Comment: When I hear about rural Taiwan I picture a farm on the roof of skyscraper.

Comment: @alamar Taiwan is actually much less urbanized than you might think. Actually it isn't very built up outside of the Greater Taipei region; there are even villages within the vicinity of Keelung and Tainan.

Comment: For the OP, you might have poor luck. My feeling is that there is probably none.

Comment: @alamar - That's funny! I did see the opposite though, sky scrapers on a hill surrounded by densely forested areas. I am currently in the country-side which is quite beautiful, very peaceful and certainly rural with no tall buildings and lots of small villages, complete with roosters waking me up very early in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machines from CTBC Bank accept Plus cards. There is one a few kilometers north of Hualien.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a generic solution for this. VISA, owners of Plus, has an [online ATM Locator](http://www.visa.com/atmlocator/index.jsp#(page:home)). According to it, there are only two Plus ATMs in Eastern Taiwan, one Hualien (Shin Kong Bank) and one in Yilan (Citibank). Being closer I took a 1h20m detour to Hualien, being sure that it would work. Unfortunately, it did not. In a bit of a panic, I headed north and hit every single ATM along highway 9. Finally, after 19 tries, I found one with the Plus logo and it was in a 7-11 (other 7-11 ones failed, so it depends on the ATM provider).

For completeness I also tried a Cirrus card at every point and none of them worked, despite being clearly aware this was a Cirrus card. I was prompted each time if I wanted to use Cirrus transaction and most machines eventually spit out the card before printing a receipt saying *Transaction Failed*.